# get people that work whole month and has code :db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

Assuming I have a table containing the following information:sq db2

```
      ID        NAME     Date1           Date2          code
      01        Tommy     2022-09-10     2022-09-30     45
      01        Tommy     2022-10-01     2022-12-31     44
      02        Elis      2022-07-13     2022-08-03     45
      02        Elis      2022-08-04     2022-08-31     45
      03        John      2022-08-10     2022-09-27     44
      04        John      2022-09-28     null           45
```

is there a way I can perform a select on the table to get the following(sql :DB2)
I Mean  get all people that work whole month and have 45 (code) för whole month(same month). Elisa  she work Aug and has 45 for whole aug as code

```
      ID         NAME     Date1           Date2          code        
             
      02        Elis      2022-07-13     2022-08-03     45           
      02        Elis      2022-08-04     2022-08-31     45
```

It is difficult for me

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Select  * from Emloyee where code='45'

Comment: This will get you employees with code = 45. Yet what did you try to address "*get all people that work whole month and have 45 (code) för whole month(same month)*"?

Comment: i think i should use date function but i don´t know which one. I tried  MONTHS_BETWEEN(date2,date2) but i didn´t get what i want !!!!!!

Comment: Date1 for Elisa is starting on the 4th of the month, so its not the entire month, can you clarify what you mean by "whole month"? Can it overlap in another row? I assume you just want an entire month covered even if its from multiple rows, correct?

Comment: @GRIV Elisa works whole Aug och she has 45 .exact  an entire month covered even if its from multiple rows.

Comment: Do you need to find workers for the specific month of August or do you want to list all months?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a subquery that `GROUPS` your data by `ID`.
2. `HAVING` `MAX` `Date2` and compare it with the last day of the month
   for `Date2`.
3. `HAVING` `MIN` `Date1` and compare it with the first day of the month
   for `Date1`.
4. `WHERE` `code` = '45'

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME, a.Date1, a.Date2, a.Code
FROM Emloyee a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
            FROM Emloyee 
            WHERE code = '45'
            GROUP BY ID, NAME 
            HAVING MAX(Date2) BETWEEN MAX(Date2) AND MAX(LAST_DAY(Date2))
            AND MIN(Date1) BETWEEN MIN(Date1) AND MAX(Date1 - (day(Date1) -1) days)
) b ON a.ID = b.ID
ORDER BY a.ID ASC
```

**Result:**

```
| ID | NAME | DATE1      | DATE2      | CODE  |
|----|------|------------|------------|-------|
| 2  | Elis | 2022-07-13 | 2022-08-03 | 45    |
| 2  | Elis | 2022-08-04 | 2022-08-31 | 45    |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1kpQDVl_).

Answer (score 0):

Similar tasks are resolved usually with the following approach. It's not a complete solution, but the way to start from.

```
WITH 
  MYTAB (ID, NAME, Date1, Date2, code) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('01', 'Tommy', DATE ('2022-09-10'), DATE ('2022-09-30'), 45)
, ('01', 'Tommy', DATE ('2022-10-01'), DATE ('2022-12-31'), 44)

--, ('02', 'Elis',  DATE ('2022-07-13'), DATE ('2022-08-03'), 45)
, ('02', 'Elis',  DATE ('2022-07-13'), DATE ('2022-07-14'), 45)
, ('02', 'Elis',  DATE ('2022-07-16'), DATE ('2022-08-03'), 45)
, ('02', 'Elis',  DATE ('2022-08-04'), DATE ('2022-08-31'), 45)

, ('03', 'John',  DATE ('2022-08-10'), DATE ('2022-09-27'), 44)
, ('04', 'John',  DATE ('2022-09-28'), CAST (null AS DATE), 45)
)
, G AS
(
-- Group number calculation with GRP
-- All records with the same (ID, NAME, GRP) have consecutive (DATE1, DATE2)
SELECT 
  T.*
, SUM
  (
    CASE 
      WHEN DATE1 = LAG (DATE2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY DATE2) + 1 
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END
  ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY DATE1)
  AS GRP 
FROM MYTAB T
WHERE CODE = 45
)
SELECT 
  G.*
, MIN (G.DATE1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME, GRP) AS DATE1_MIN
, MAX (G.DATE2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME, GRP) AS DATE2_MAX
FROM G
```

| ID | NAME | DATE1 | DATE2 | CODE | GRP | DATE1_MIN | DATE2_MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Tommy | 2022-09-10 | 2022-09-30 | 45 | 1 | 2022-09-10 | 2022-09-30 |
| 02 | Elis | 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-14 | 45 | 1 | 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-14 |
| 02 | Elis | 2022-07-16 | 2022-08-03 | 45 | 2 | 2022-07-16 | 2022-08-31 |
| 02 | Elis | 2022-08-04 | 2022-08-31 | 45 | 2 | 2022-07-16 | 2022-08-31 |
| 04 | John | 2022-09-28 |  | 45 | 1 | 2022-09-28 |  |

You calculate an additional "Group" column (GRP in the example) first.
All records with the same (ID, NAME, GRP) have consecutive (DATE1, DATE2) date intervals.
Finally (min, max) dates are calculated for every such a group.

The most difficult part is to construct an expression for every (min, max) interval to understand, if it covers some whole **unknown** month in common case (it's easy for some **fixed known** month, of course).